# Datatable row expansion event

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces, expansion

I am using Primefaces 3.0 with JSF 2.0. I have a datatable with expansion enabled. I wanted to call a bean method when the user clicks on rowToggler. Basically I wanted to load the expansion details only when the user clicks the expand button. I can't see a server side callback for row expansion in the documentation. Please let me know if I can have any workaround for this problem.

Thanks and Regards,
Renju

Comment: I see this in the issue tracker (URL below). I'm looking forward to this as well. http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/issues/detail?id=2277

Answer (score 7):

Following the link Howard provided in the question comment I could see that this was implemented in PF 3.4:

**XHTML**

```
<p:ajax event="rowToggle" listener="#{tableBean.onRowToggle}" update=":form:growl" />
```

**Bean**

```
public void onRowToggle(ToggleEvent event) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO,
                                        "Row State " + event.getVisibility(),
                                        "Model:" + ((Car) event.getData()).getModel());

    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);
}
```

You can see this in the showcase:
https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/expansion.xhtml

Comment: I am using this approach and it works fine, until the user filters the datatable. Then event.getData() returns invalid data( new Car() object in your case). Any ideas why is this happening? Thanks.

Comment: A little late, but I had the same problem and in my case the solution was to add the `filteredValue` attribute to the datatable.

Answer (score 0):

Primefaces' rowToggler already loads content with ajax so you should be fine ;-)

From the manual:

> p:rowToggler component places an expand/collapse icon, clicking on a collapsed row loads expanded content with ajax.